# CSS link nested styles

Tags: css

I need to create a lot of link styles:

```
  a:link {color: one;}
  a:visited {color: two;}
  a:hover {color: three;}
  a:active {color: four;}
```

but for a.1 - a.10

Is there any way to cut the code to more compact variant?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `.1` or `.10` are valid class names?

Comment: It's an example, I can give them other names, I just mean there's much of them

Comment: use SASS to generate the code

Comment: Do you need a different style for each link?

Comment: Yes, I do _____

Comment: We need more information about the structure and naming convention you're using to further assist you. Please make sure to add a 'minimum viable code' so people can work on the issue on here. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelHager already got an answer, thanks. Somehow my previous comment was deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with simple CSS, you may use SASS to do what you want.

Here's the [SASS documentation about nesting](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules#nesting) !

You'll be able to create something like that :

```
.my-class-1 a, .my-class-2 a {
  :link {
    color: one;        
  }
  :visited {
    color: two;
  } 
  [...]     
}
```

And if you need multiple style for your class you can still nest your `a` like that, it's still easier to read and faster to write :

```
 .my-class-1 a {
  :link {
    color: one;        
  }
  :visited {
    color: two;
  } 
  [...]     
}
.my-class-2 a {
  :link {
    color: three;        
  }
  :visited {
    color: four;
  } 
  [...]     
}
```

Comment: Your welcome ! I just edited my answer since I saw you have different style for all your class :)